# Conditional removal of rows in R

Tags: r, matrix, conditional-statements

Consider the following matrix:

```
testMat <- matrix(c(1,2,1,3,
                 3,2,3,3,
                 1,3,1,3,
                 2,3,3,3,
                 3,3,3,3,
                 3,2,3,1), byrow = T, ncol = 4)
```

and following condition:

```
cond <- c(0,0) # binary
```

**Problem:** If `cond[1]` is `0` and there is a `1` in either the first or third column, the corresponding rows will be removed. Similarly if `cond[2]` is `0` and there is a `1` in either the second or fourth column, the corresponding rows will be removed. For example the new matrix will be:

```
newMat <- testMat[-c(1,3,6),] # for cond <- c(0,0)
newMat <- testMat[-c(1,3),] # for cond <- c(0,1)
newMat <- testMat[-c(6),] # for cond <- c(1,0)
newMat <- testMat # for cond <- c(1,1)
```

**I tried in following way which is both wrong and clumsy.**

```
newMat <- testMat[-(cond[1] == 0 & testMat[,c(1,3)] == 1),]
newMat <- newMat[-(cond[2] == 0 & newMat[,c(2,4)] == 1),]
```

Can you help to find a base R solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ugly, but seems to work:
(generalized for length of `cond`, assuming that the matrix has `length(cond)*2` columns)

```
keepRows <- apply(testMat, 1,
                  function(rw, cond) {
                    logicrow <- vector(length=2)
                    for (b in 1:length(cond)) {
                      logicrow[b] <- ifelse(cond[b]==0, all(rw[b]!=1) & all(rw[length(cond)+b]!=1), TRUE)
                    }
                    all(logicrow)
                  }, cond = cond)

newMat <- testMat[keepRows, ]
```

(edited according to comment)

Comment: It seems like the output is wrong for cond = c(1,0)

Comment: You are right, I mixed up the columns in the `ifelse(...)` part. Now corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 1) cond can be of arbitrary length, 2) testMat has an even number of columns, and 3) the rule is to look at the i-th and (i+2)-th column of testMat

```
cond=c(0,0)

unlist(
  sapply(
    1:length(cond),
    function(i){
      j=rowSums(testMat[,c(i,i+2)]==1)
      if (cond[i]==0 & sum(j)>0) which(j>0) else nrow(testMat)+1
    }
  )
)
[1] 1 3 6
```

which returns the rows which satisfy your conditions, you can then remove these

```
testMat[-.Last.value,]
```

Comment: This works well but when cond = c(1,1) or cases when there is no 1 in the matrix, the whole matrix gets vanished. I can get around by using one more condition but I would like to avoid it.

Comment: @Rel_Ai True, check modification.